# Failed to load resource (file not found) Electron js cannot import or export

Tags: javascript, import, electron, node-modules, require

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I am using latest version of npm, node.js and electron.

My html file calls upon a `terrautils.js`:

```html
<script type="module" src="./terrautils.js"></script>
```

My terrautils.js file has first line as:

```js
import { LCDClient, Coin } from './node_modules/@terra-money/terra.js';
```

Which is the link to an npm module that I want to use, and I have it installed and have confirmed that the folder is really there using file explorer. I also know the module works perfectly file, because this issue only happens when I run using `npm start` but when I run using `node terrautils.js` and swap from using `import` to using `require`, it works perfectly fine.

This is something to do with electron I think, and not sure what to do. My main.js has `createWindow` function like:

```js
function createWindow (site) {
  var win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 700,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      devTools: true,
    }
  })

  win.loadFile(site)
}
```

I do not care about security, I just want this to work. Thank you.

Comment: When you install a node module, you should not give the folder path, but just specify its name. For example : `import { LCDClient, Coin } from '@terra-money/terra.js'` (as mentionned in the [@terra-money/terra.js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@terra-money/terra.js).

Comment: This still does not solve the problem @Dony

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Change html invoking of the js file to this instead:

```html
    <script>
        require('./terrautils.js')
    </script>
```

dont know how it works, but it does.